# Ruby: substring to a certain length and also to last whitespace within substring

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to truncate a long string of text to a certain length, but want to also make sure that the truncated result ends at a whitespace. I am also going to append an ellipsis afterwards.

For example this:

```
"This is a very long string that has more characters than I want in it."
```

becomes this:

```
"This is a very long string that..."
```

I am starting with this but obviously this doesn't deal with the problem of ending the string on whitespace.

```
<%= item.description[0..30] %>&hellip;
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
s[0..30].gsub(/\s\w+\s*$/, '...')
```

The original answer didn't work in the case where the 30 character substring ended on a whitespace character. This solves that.

```
>> desc="This is some text it is really long"

>> desc[0..30].gsub(/\s\w+$/,'...')
"This is some text it is really "

>> desc[0..30].gsub(/\s\w+\s*$/,'...')
"This is some text it is..."
```

Comment: Thanks for the pure ruby answer!  Worked perfectly.

Comment: This is not quite what most people want.  It adds the ellipsis regardless of whether the string is actually longer than 30 characters.

Comment: Also this answer throws out the last word for no reason, even it there is no need for it. Woudn't be the string "This is some text it is really..." be more expected outcome?

Comment: Three periods is not the same as an ellipsis. Please, where you can, use a Unicode ellipsis character, not three periods.

Answer (score 49):

If you're using Rails 4+ you should just use the built-in [`truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) helper method, e.g.:

```
<%= truncate item.description, length: 30, separator: /\w+/ %>
```

The string "…" will be appended to truncated text; to specify a different string, use the `:omission` option, e.g. `omission: "xxx"`.

For Rails 3.x the `:separator` option must be a string. Giving `:separator => " "` will be fine in many cases, but only catches spaces and not other whitespace. One compromise would be to use [`String#squish`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.22.5/classes/String.html#method-i-squish), which replaces all sequences of whitespace with a single space (and also trims leading and trailing whitespace), e.g. `"foo\n\tbar ".squish` yields `"foo bar"`. It would look like this:

```
<%= truncate item.description.squish, :length => 30, :separator => /\w/,
                                      :omission => "&hellip;" %>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use regex in the separator argument

Comment: I am using rails 3.2.13 and Regexp is not supposed for separator.

NoMethodError: undefined method `mb_chars' for /\w/:Regexp

Comment: I've updated the answer with some notes on using `truncate` with Rails 3.x.

Answer (score 8):

@evfwcqcg's answer is very good. I found it did not work well when

1. The string contained other characters that are non-space not alphanumerical.
2. The string is shorter than the desired length.

Demonstration:

```
>> s = "How about we put some ruby method Class#Method in our string"
=> "How about we put some ruby method Class#Method in our string"
>> s[0..41].gsub(/\s\w+\s*$/, '...')
=> "How about we put some ruby method Class#Me"
>> s[0..999].gsub(/\s\w+\s*$/, '...')
=> "How about we put some ruby method Class#Method in our..."
```

This is not what I expected.

Here is what I am using to fix this:

```
def truncate s, length = 30, ellipsis = '...'
  if s.length > length
    s.to_s[0..length].gsub(/[^\w]\w+\s*$/, ellipsis)
  else
    s
  end
end
```

When doing tests, here is the output:

```
>> s = "This is some text it is really long"
=> "This is some text it is really long"
>> truncate s
=> "This is some text it is..."
```

Still behave as expected.

```
>> s = "How about we put some ruby method Class#Method in our string"
=> "How about we put some ruby method Class#Method in our string"
>> truncate s, 41
=> "How about we put some ruby method Class..."
>> truncate s, 999
=> "How about we put some ruby method Class#Method in our string"
```

This is more like it.

Comment: Although this is better than @evfwcqcg's answer still I do not know why you would like to take out last word even if it fits in to the limit. In case of your exmple - why you see the text "This is some text it is" as desired result when "This is some text it is really" has 30 characters and it ends at whitespace as well.

Comment: @gorn Because once you add the ellipsis, it's going to be over 30 chars. Granted, if the ellipsis's length is over the last word's length, its going to be over 30 characters anyway. But in most cases, with the ellipsis being "...", it would only go over 30 if the last word is 1 character, which I think does not happen very often. Do you have any suggestions to make this better?

Comment: I understand that it will "work in most cases", so my ranting has more academic than practical value, but thats the way I am when I see "incorrect" code. Sorry about that. I have posted a solution as a separate answer, because it got too long for a comment. Feel free to add your thoughts there.

Comment: An ellipsis is only one character long, if you use the Unicode ellipsis character. Please do.

Answer (score 3):

```
desc.gsub(/([\w\s]{30}).+/,'\1...')
```

Expanding on the answer by @evfwcqcg, this is a pure regex that solves the problem of trailing whitespace.

```
irb(main):031:0> desc="This is some text it is really long"
irb(main):033:0> desc.gsub(/([\w\s]{30}).+/,'\1...')
=> "This is some text it is really..."
irb(main):034:0> desc="This is some text it is really"
=> "This is some text it is really"
irb(main):035:0> desc.gsub(/([\w\s]{30}).+/,'\1...')
=> "This is some text it is really"
irb(main):036:0> desc="This is some text it is real"
=> "This is some text it is real"
irb(main):037:0> desc.gsub(/([\w\s]{30}).+/,'\1...')
=> "This is some text it is real"
```

Comment: This is plain wrong solution. If you try with the original string "This is a very long string that has more characters than I want in it." than you get "This is a very long string tha..." ...

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised that none of the answers is really correct (or limited by using rails helper) although this is very old question, so here is the solution.

Lets clearly formulate what it the goal first. We want truncate string `s` to 30 characters and cut the last word out as well if it can not entirely fit in. We also want to truncate trailing spaces from the result and add ellipsis, if the text was shortened.

If the text is longer then limit, than the shortening is as easy as

```
s[0,s.rindex(/\s/,30)].rstrip + '...'
```

If we wanted the entire result to be max 30 characters, than it is as simple as subtracting the length of ellipse from 30. So because we use three dots (and not one three-dot character) than we need

```
s[0,s.rindex(/\s/,27)].rstrip + '...'
```

And the final result (with the test whether we need to truncate at all) is:

```
if s.length<=30
  s
else
  s[0,s.rindex(/\s/,27)].rstrip + '...'
end
```

Thats it.

---

*Note: There are some shady cases, when the desired result is not obvious. Here they are:*

- *If the string ends with lots of spaces (`s= "Helo word     "`) but is shorter than 30. Should the spaces be preserved? - Currently they are.*
- *The same as above, but the spaces at the end cross the limit o 30. Like in  (`s= "Twentyseven chars long text       "`) - Currently all spaces ad the end are truncated and ellipsis added.*

Answer (score 0):

```
class String
  def trunca(length=100, ellipsis='...')
    self.length > length ? self[0..length].gsub(/\s*\S*\z/, '').rstrip+ellipsis : self.rstrip
  end
end
```

Example:

```
-bash> irb
2.0.0p247 :001 > class String
2.0.0p247 :002?>     def trunca(length=100, ellipsis='...')
2.0.0p247 :003?>         self.length > length ? self[0..length].gsub(/\s*\S*\z/, '').rstrip+ellipsis : self.rstrip
2.0.0p247 :004?>       end
2.0.0p247 :005?>   end
 => nil 
2.0.0p247 :006 > s = "This is a very long string that has more characters than I want to display."
 => "This is a very long string that has more characters than I want to display." 
2.0.0p247 :007 > s.trunca(20)
 => "This is a very long..." 
2.0.0p247 :008 > s.trunca(31)
 => "This is a very long string that..."
```

Comment: I think that the first rstrip is not necesarry.

Comment: `self[0..length]` will return length+1 characters.